# Mapping json object to interface with HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm having some problem understanding how I can transform my json response to fit my interface for a multiselect.

Here's the response that I'm getting from the api:

```js
[
  {
    "TransportTypeId": 1,
    "Code": "RT  ",
    "Name": "Round Trip          "
  },
  {
    "TransportTypeId": 2,
    "Code": "N/A       ",
    "Name": "UnAllocated         "
  },
  {
    "TransportTypeId": 3,
    "Code": "OWOut     ",
    "Name": "OneWay Out          "
  },
  {
    "TransportTypeId": 4,
    "Code": "OWHome    ",
    "Name": "OneWay Home         "
  }
]
```

This is the interface that I'm trying to map it to:

```
export interface IMultiSelectOption {
    id: any;
    name: string;
    isLabel?: boolean;
    parentId?: any;
    params?: any;
    classes?: string;
}
```

I would like to map `TransportTypeId` to `id` and `Name` to `name`.

As I said I'm using the new `HttpClient` in angular 4 and I'm having some difficulties finding any example like this.

this is my get function:

```
getTransportTypes(): Observable<TransportType> {
    let options: TransportType;
    let multiselect: IMultiSelectOption
    let requestUri = '/BaseData/TransportTypes';
    debugger;
    return this.http.get<TransportType>(`${this.flighttransportcapacityUrl}${requestUri}`)
}
```

This is returning the response and mapping it to TransportType that is exactly the same as the response properties:

```
export class TransportType{
    TransportTypeId: number;
    Code: string;
    Name: string;
}
```

This is working correctly but I was thinking there should be some easier way of converting the response to `IMultiSelectOption` then to loop over the result of the get function?

Including my dirty way of doing it.

```
    this.base.getTransportTypes().map(item => this.convertToMultiSelect(item)).subscribe(options => this.transportOptions = options)
```

and the convertfunction:

```
convertToMultiSelect(item: any): IMultiSelectOption[] {
    debugger;
    let v = item;

    let options = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

        options.push({ id: item[i].TransportTypeId, name: item[i].Name})
    }

    return options;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to optimize the `TransportType` to `IMultiSelectOption` transformation? If yes, could you include your current version (the loop you mentioned) in your question?

Comment: added it to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to convert a list of objects to a new list of the same size, use the `map()` method. So the code could look like this:

```
this.base.getTransportTypes()
  .map(transportTypes => transportTypes
    .map(trType => ({ id: trType.TransportTypeId, name: trType.Name }))
  )
  .subscribe(options => this.transportOptions = options)
```

Or if you want to keep the  `convertToMultiSelect` method:

```
convertToMultiSelect(items: TransportType[]): IMultiSelectOption[] {
  return items.map(item => ({ id: item.TransportTypeId, name: item.Name }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this helped me out! , although i just found that material had made it available for multiselect on their <md-select> so I switched to that.

Thanks again.